# How to write Chained Exception Java classes

Tags: java, exception

Specifically, which constructors should be overridden to qualify an exception as [chainable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html)?

`Throwable(Throwable cause)`, `Throwable(String message, Throwable cause)`, or both?

Resources:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html

---

> The following example shows how to use a chained exception.:

```
try {

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new SampleException("Other IOException", e);
}
```

Comment: Man you guys are fast... updated the subject and added some context to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear what you mean by "chainable" here.

Given the links that you gave however, I'll assume that you mean that a `Throwable` has another `Throwable` as a cause.

In this case you have no choice but to use the appropriate constructor; for instance:

```
public class Root
    extends Exception
{
    public Root(final String msg, final Throwable cause)
    {
        super(msg, cause);
    }
}
```

Another, less known solution, but which exists since Java 7, is to "suppress" the exception. See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-).

Which means that you should first define what you mean by "chained exceptions". An exception, by its nature, is pretty much "final"; the need to embed exceptions into other exceptions is rare, but not unheard of (as to suppressed exceptions, see [here](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/filesystem/deletion/KeepGoingDeletionVisitor.java) for an example)

So, define your use case first and foremost!

Comment: Very cool about suppressed exceptions. Thanks.  

So, it seems that we can use either of those two constructors to get [chained exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html) in a way that "`getCause()` returns the exception that caused the current exception, and `initCause()` sets the current exception's cause."

Comment: Not quite. If you suppress an exception, it will not be seen as a "cause". At this point I believe the best way is to experiment and see what is the best for you. Personally, since the advent of suppressed exceptions I rarely see the need for `initCause()`, but your mileage may vary ;)